# Negative values causes wrong y-axis highcharts

Tags: highcharts

The zero value for left axis is switched to "-80", zero value for right axis is switched to "-8" and so forth (see image attached). 
I have the following options for the two y-axises:

```
 yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        categories: ["-80","-60", "-40", "-20", "0", "20", "40", "60", "80", "100", "120", "140", "160", "180", "200"],
        tickInterval: 20,
        min: -80,
        max: 200,
        floor: -80,
        ceiling: 200,
        labels: {
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'DB 1 (kr/innsatt høne)',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        categories: ["-8","-6","-4","-2","0","2","4","6","8","10","12","14","16","18","20"],
        tickInterval: 2,
        min: -8,
        max: 20,
        floor: -8,
        ceiling: 20,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Fôrpris (kr/kg fôr), Eggpris (kr/kg egg)',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value},0',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        opposite: true,
    }],
```

[image: The zero value for left axis is switched to "-80", zero value for right axis is switched to "-8"]

[Live demo](http://coretrek.bouvet.no/projects/Nortura/highchart.php)

Anyone have some suggestions for how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Set alignTicks as false in chart options.

```
chart: {
        alignTicks: false
},
```

Docs:
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks

Comment: That did not help, unfortunately

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo ?

Comment: Honestly In you chart configuration I don't see alignTicks set as false.

Comment: I removed it, as it did not work. Have updated it with alignTicks set as false, so that you can verify

Comment: The problem is that you use categories, mixed with number values. Remove categories on yAxis, set min / max values and tickInterval. Better is using jsfiddle, becuase when will be easier to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `min` and `max` in combination with `categories`. These do not connect in the way you are expecting them to.

Using categories only replaces the numeric value `0`, `1`, ..., on that axis with the string that you have in your categories array, so the value `0` on your first y-axis will be replaced with the category label `"-80"`. The values on the axis that do not have an index within your categories array will simply show as their own numeric value.

In your case I suggest removing `min` and `max` completely if you expect all categories to be showing. However if the values of your series relate to those specific numeric values then you'll be better of with correctly spacing your ticks with `tickPositions` or similar, and not using categories at all.

Comment: Yes, strongly recommend not using categories on any of the axes here. Looking at the chart example, it seems all that is needed is an appropriate tickInterval to achieve the desired result.

Comment: I have to use these categories, as these are the exact ranges demanded by the customer

Comment: Give us a JSFiddle and it should be easy to demonstrate. Remove categories completely. It won't be much different, just the tick labels, and that can be quickly fixed.

Comment: See [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/c9yco4qe/) that has no categories.

Comment: Thank you for your example @Ondkloss, but I already solved this using alignTicks: false, removing categories on yAxis, setting min / max values and tickInterval. See answer above. Your answer probably also works though:)

Comment: Then I hope that answer is edited because `alignTicks` is completely irrelevant to the issue you are experiencing. Doesn't have to be used at all as there is an equal number of ticks on each axis.